# unable to connect client process to k8s pod from host machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking

I have a sctp server running on k8s pod with the below service details. I am able to connect this server if my client is installed in a docker container. However, I try to connect server directly from my host machine, then it is not connecting. Why? Is docker and k8s networking namespace are overlapped? docker and k8s are both installed on my host machine where I am trying to run the client.

```
`/home> sudo kubectl get svc -A  | grep service-ricplt-e2term-sctp-alpha
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-sctp-alpha            NodePort    10.109.8.172     <none>        36422:32222/SCTP                  3h10m
/home>
`
```

docker ip

```
`root@4d358d78aeda:/e2stub# 
root@4d358d78aeda:/e2stub# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.4  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:11:00:04  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 23818  bytes 83378319 (83.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15664  bytes 1190328 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@4d358d78aeda:/e2stub# `
```

tried to run client from host machine where k8s is installed